# How can I get text from this span class using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I need to get the value of 5,2329 from this code using selenium in python. What should I do to properly do it?

`<span class="chart-info-val ng-binding" ng-bind="graphicView.bidvalue">5,2329</span>`

.

Comment: Please make sure to add your code trails and the error messages for better assistance.

Comment: You can either use a `css selector` (best recommendation) as answerd below by @supputuri or `XPATH`'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with the below code.

```
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.chart-info-val.ng-binding").text)
```

Comment: It worked, thanks.

But what should I if there is more elements with the same span class="chart-info-val ng-binding"

Comment: `find_element_` will always pick the first matching element though there are multiple elements that matches the locator. If you want to point to any specific instance then either you can refine the locator to point to the exact element or get multiple elements using `find_element*s*` and then use index.

Comment: If you feel the issue is resolved with this or any answer please make sure to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left hand side of the answer. Also upvote the answer for the benefit of future readers.